# PostgreSQL copy command generate primary key id

Tags: postgresql

I have a CSV file with two columns: city and zipcode. I want to be able to copy this file into a PostgreSQL table using the `copy` command and at the same time auto generate the `id` value.

The table has the following columns: `id`, `city`, and `zipcode`.

My CSV file has only: `city` and `zipcode`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The [COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) should do that all by itself if your table uses a `serial` column for the `id`:

> If there are any columns in the table that are not in the column list, COPY FROM will insert the default values for those columns.

So you should be able to say:

```
copy table_name(city, zipcode) from ...
```

and the `id` will be generated as usual. If you don't have a `serial` column for `id` (or a manually attached sequence), then you could hook up a sequence by hand, do your COPY, and then detach the sequence.

Comment: Here's how I copied data from CSV to Postgres: \copy company_infos(email, url, created_at, updated_at) FROM '/Users/john/company_infos_heroku4.csv' WITH(FORMAT csv, HEADER true);